# Why are individual SELECT queries running when an all-encompassing SELECT already ran? (Rails/ActiveRecord)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, query-optimization

I have the following code (note the `includes` and the `.each`):

```
subscribers = []
mailgroup.mailgroup_members.opted_to_receive_email.includes(:roster_contact, :roster_info).each { |m|
  subscribers << { :EmailAddress => m.roster_contact.member_email,
                   :Name => m.roster_contact.member_name,
                   :CustomFields => [ { :Key => 'gender', 
                                        :Value => m.roster_info.gender.present? ? m.roster_info.gender : 'X' 
                                    } ] 
                  } if m.roster_contact.member_email.present?
}
subscribers
```

Correspondingly, I see the following in my logs (i.e. `select * from ROSTER_INFO ... IN (...)`):

```
SELECT `ROSTER_INFO`.* FROM `ROSTER_INFO` WHERE `ROSTER_INFO`.`ID` IN ('1450', '1000', '1111')
```

Yet immediately after that there are `select * from ROSTER_INFO` for each ID already specified in the `IN` list of the previous query:

```
RosterInfo Load (84.8ms)  SELECT `ROSTER_INFO`.* FROM `ROSTER_INFO` WHERE `ROSTER_INFO`.`ID` = '1450' LIMIT 1
RosterInfo Load (59.2ms)  SELECT `ROSTER_INFO`.* FROM `ROSTER_INFO` WHERE `ROSTER_INFO`.`ID` = '1000' LIMIT 1
RosterInfo Load (56.8ms)  SELECT `ROSTER_INFO`.* FROM `ROSTER_INFO` WHERE `ROSTER_INFO`.`ID` = '1111' LIMIT 1
```

If `select *` had already been done on `ROSTER_INFO` on all IDs of interest (`IN (...)`), why is another `select *` being done again for each of the same IDs? Doesn't `ActiveRecord` already know all the `ROSTER_INFO` columns for each ID?

(Meanwhile, there are no individual queries for `ROSTER_CONTACT`, yet if I remove `:roster_contact` from the `includes` method, then `ROSTER_INFO` is not queried again, but `ROSTER_CONTACT` is.)

---

**RosterInfo model (abridged)**

```
class RosterInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'
end
```

**RosterContact model (abridged)**

```
class RosterContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  has_many :mailgroup_members, foreign_key: 'rosterID'
  has_many :mailgroups, through: :mailgroup_members

  has_one :roster_info, foreign_key: 'ID'     # can use this line
  #belongs_to :roster_info, foreign_key: 'ID' # or this with no difference

  def member_name                             # I added this method to this
    roster_info.member_name                   # question only *after* having
  end                                         # figured out the problem.
end
```

**RosterWeb model (abridged)**

```
class RosterWeb < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'
end
```

**Mailgroup model (abridged)**

```
class Mailgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  has_many :mailgroup_members, foreign_key: 'mailCatID'

  has_one :mailing_list, foreign_key: :legacy_id
end
```

**MailgroupMember model (abridged)**

```
class MailgroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'ID'

  belongs_to :mailgroup, foreign_key: 'mailCatID'
  belongs_to :roster_contact, foreign_key: 'rosterID'
  belongs_to :roster_info, foreign_key: 'rosterID'
  belongs_to :roster_web, foreign_key: 'rosterID'

  scope :opted_to_receive_email, joins(:roster_web).where('ROSTER_WEB.receiveEmail=?', 1)
end
```

Comment: what does your database model look like?

Comment: @Michael I am not sure what you mean by "database model". Do you want to see table schemas or model associations or something else? And for which model(s)?

Comment: Model for `roster_info.rb` definitely, other than some unconventional associations, some gems can also change activerecord behavior

Comment: @prusswan I have added all the relevant models and the entire Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be related to `m.roster_contact.member_name` -- unfortunately I made `member_name` a method of `roster_contact` that itself (indirectly) queried `roster_info.member_name`. I resolved this by changing the line

```
:Name => m.roster_contact.member_name,
```

to directly query `roster_info` as follows

```
:Name => m.roster_info.member_name,
```

I am sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stick my neck out and say that this is probably an in-flight optimization by your query engine. The 'IN' is typically used to compare large sets of keys, the most efficient way of resolving three keys (assuming ID is the key) would be to retrieve each row by key, as has happened.

Comment: I can't see this being an optimization since it is querying each object twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RosterInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :roster_contact, foreign_key: 'ID'  
end

class RosterContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :roster_info, foreign_key: 'ID' 
end
```

I don't know what is the premise for having bi-directional `has_one`, but I suspect it will turn out badly. Probably change one of them to `belongs_to`. Do the same for the other bi-directional `has_one` associations.

Another thing is that you are using 'ID' for the foreign_key column, where the usual practice is `roster_contact_id` or whichever class you are referencing.

Edit:

On closer examination, `RosterInfo`, `RosterContact`, `RosterWeb` look like separate tables for what should be a single record since they are all having the same set of **mutual `has_one` associations**. This is something that should be addressed on the schema level, but right now you should be able to drop the `has_one` associations from *one* of the three models to solve your immediate problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughtful answer! I tried to keep this question as clean as possible. The truth of the matter is that I am dealing with a **legacy database**, which would be *very difficult* to modify, as it would also imply modifying legacy code which is just as badly designed as this schema. Each of the "Roster" tables (`RosterInfo`, `RosterContact`, and `RosterWeb`) only have an `ID` column to associate the rows (models). With this info, what would your advice be?

Comment: As illustrated in the diagram, you can do without the `has_one` associations in one of the models, but you will have to reference the models from the single model that has access to the other two, which shouldn't be a problem since they are all sharing the same 'ID' anyway.

Comment: Again, thanks for your incredible effort. I figured out the problem, but the excessive associations were not it. I stripped them down to one necessary association, and the problem persisted (regardless of `has_one` or `belongs_to`). The issue turned out to be related to `m.roster_contact.member_name` -- unfortunately I made `member_name` a method of `roster_contact` that itself (indirectly) queried `roster_info.member_name`. I resolved this by changing that line to *directly* query `roster_info` as follows: `m.roster_info.member_name`. Again, I thank you for your effort!

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty nonetheless, as your suggestions made me dig deeper, and ultimately determine the problem and solution. Thanks again!